# audit logs are unavailable, timeout problem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Previously logs worked, all of a sudden they do not work anymore. I have changed in web.config the timeout value by pasting this line

```
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

Is IIS in need to restart? Logs are still not working.

Comment: when you make a change in web.config file, it will recycle the app automatically.  what error you are getting for audit logs?

Answer (score 0):

The error was a generic one. What I have done is deactivate reporting and re-activate reporting and they went back working.